# Images in OOXML (Office Open XML) standard documents are damaged. Where I can find a good one?

Tags: openxml, docx, iso

We are working on a project to deal with OOXML format, specifically DOCX format. We downloaded PDFs from ISO site (http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html) but found all images in the PDF are black. Some images have colored lines but none of them has text.

Is there anyone read the standard?

Where I can get a good document with good images.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the ECMA-376 version of the standard at the following [link](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).  I would download the third edition set of the pdf's as they are the most recent to date.

Comment: I downloaded ecma version too. But the image is still black. See page 689 (logic page 679), there is a picture show how to do toggle properties. It should have text in the picture, but what's inside is just black background and red arrows.